Error to parse pickled data to/from database
I am trying to store pickled object into database and unpickle it back.
Data is being stored in database, however after reading data its throwing an error during unpickle.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "read_pickle_data.py", line 49, in <module>
   unpickled = pickle.loads(item[0].encode())
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
_pickle.UnpicklingError: unpickling stack underflow

Environment Details:

Database: MariaDB
Python: 3.11
Pickle Protocol: 1 (Also tried with 2 and pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

(Below is the code I am using. task variable is used to control the insert/read database operation.)
Code:
import MySQLdb
import pickle


class Car:
    def __init__(self, model, year, color):
        self.model = model
        self.year = year
        self.color = color

    def display_info(self):
        return f"{self.year} {self.color} {self.model}"


conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="<host>", port=<port>,
                       user="<user>", password="<passwd>", database="<db>")
cursor = conn.cursor()

task = "read"
if task == "insert":
    car = Car("123", 2024, "red")
    car_obj_serialized = pickle.dumps(car, protocol=1)
    car_obj_escaped = conn.escape_string(car_obj_serialized)

    print(car_obj_serialized)
    print(car_obj_escaped)

    query = """INSERT INTO car_models(car_pickled_object, status) VALUES("%s", "%s");""" % (
        car_obj_escaped,
        "Booked"
    )

    cursor.execute(query)
    conn.commit()
else:
    query = """SELECT * FROM car_models WHERE id=10"""
    cursor.execute(query)

    row = cursor.fetchone()

    pickled_obj = row[1]
    car_obj_escaped = conn.escape_string(pickled_obj)
    
    print(pickled_obj)
    print(car_obj_escaped)
    
    unpickled_obj = pickle.loads(car_obj_escaped)

During read I tried to remove car_obj_escaped = conn.escape_string(pickled_obj) line and added car_obj_escaped.encode(). But, it's still not working.
- Insert logs:
car_obj_serialized:
---
b'ccopy_reg\n_reconstructor\nq\x00(c__main__\nCar\nq\x01c__builtin__\nobject\nq\x02Ntq\x03Rq\x04}q\x05(X\x05\x00\x00\x00modelq\x06X\x03\x00\x00\x00123q\x07X\x04\x00\x00\x00yearq\x08M\xe8\x07X\x05\x00\x00\x00colorq\tX\x03\x00\x00\x00redq\nub.'

car_obj_escaped
---
b'ccopy_reg\\n_reconstructor\\nq\\0(c__main__\\nCar\\nq\x01c__builtin__\\nobject\\nq\x02Ntq\x03Rq\x04}q\x05(X\x05\\0\\0\\0modelq\x06X\x03\\0\\0\\0123q\x07X\x04\\0\\0\\0yearq\x08M\xe8\x07X\x05\\0\\0\\0colorq\tX\x03\\0\\0\\0redq\\nub.'

- Read logs
pickled_obj
---
b'ccopy_reg\n_reconstructor\nq\0(c__main__\nCar\nqx01c__builtin__\nobject\nqx02Ntqx03Rqx04}qx05(Xx05\0\0\0modelqx06Xx03\0\0\0123qx07Xx04\0\0\0yearqx08Mxe8x07Xx05\0\0\0colorq      Xx03\0\0\0redq\nub.'

car_obj_escaped
---
b"b\\'ccopy_reg\\\\n_reconstructor\\\\nq\\\\0(c__main__\\\\nCar\\\\nqx01c__builtin__\\\\nobject\\\\nqx02Ntqx03Rqx04}qx05(Xx05\\\\0\\\\0\\\\0modelqx06Xx03\\\\0\\\\0\\\\0123qx07Xx04\\\\0\\\\0\\\\0yearqx08Mxe8x07Xx05\\\\0\\\\0\\\\0colorq\tXx03\\\\0\\\\0\\\\0redq\\\\nub.\\'"

Trying to store and read pickled data to/from database in Python3.

Don't use string formatting to store data in the DB, use prepared statements with parameters. This will most likely solve the problem.

Alternately, use some other encoding such as hex dump or base64 encoding to avoid the need for escapes.

You shouldn't do that 4th escape-again step - mysql should give you the unescaped string. But there is a problem (for instance) with the 1 (encoded as \x01 in your print of the data). The escaped string still has \x01 but when you read it back, its the string "x01". I'm not sure whether parameterizing like @barmar suggests is going to avoid this problem. Post your experience and let us know!
